# how to get email id from database in WordPress woocommerece and store it to the java script variable?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I've an issue while storing email id when the order is generated in woocommerece. i'm retrieving email but the error comes when i store this email id to java script variable.

```
<script>
     var email = <?php echo $order->get_billing_email();  ?>;
 </script>
```

this is the error when the page is loaded.

[error in my code from Source of web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQ8tn.png)

Comment: `var email = "<?php echo $order->get_billing_email();  ?>";` or `var email = <?php echo json_encode($order->get_billing_email());  ?>;`

Comment: Please pass your email as a string.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing quotes on the string value so wrap it with quotes to make it a valid javascript string.

```
var email = '<?php echo $order->get_billing_email();  ?>';
```

Or simply encode it to JSON string which keeps always a valid Javascript data.

```
var email = <?php echo $order->get_billing_email();  ?>;
```

Comment: @johnli : can u share your current code and browser output

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `wp_localize_script`? You can achieve the same result.

```
wp_localize_script(
    'test-script',
    'orderDetails',
    array(
        'email' => 'name@example.com',
    )
);
```

This will make an object called `orderDetails` available to you in the script enqueued with the handle `test-script`. You can access the email `orderDetails.email`. Also this must be defined after the targeted script has been enqueued to work successful.

Note, while I'm not completely sure what you're trying to achieve here. I cannot stress enough how bad it is to pass personally information of any kind using `wp_localize_script` or the by creating inline script as you initial tried. If you wish to get access to sensitive information use an [ajax_action](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) instead.

To elaborate more without getting to far into the weeds. Using the methods that result in JavaScript code being add directly to the initial printing of the page means that it is readable for anyone viewing the page source.

To get a general idea of what it mean, try using `wp_localize_script` and you should find an additional script element right above where the targeted script is loaded in the resulting HTML.